# Annotation does not apply label height and width configuration, how to apply shape borderRadius configuration in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Live demo with steps to reproduce
https://jsfiddle.net/ankitkumar148/e8xrvc65/11/

Configuration -

```
annotations: [{
       shapes: [ {
           point: '3',
           type: 'rect',
           width: 20,
           height: 20,
           x: -10,
           y: -25
       }],
       labels: [ {
           point: '4',
             borderRadius: 2,
           borderWidth: 2,
           borderColor: 'red',
           style: {
               fontSize: '12px', 
               width: 20,
               height: 20
           },
          shape: 'rect',
          text: ' '
       }]
   }]
```

In above configuration,

- **for point 3 -** Is there any configuration to add border radius to shape, just like we have for point 4 with label annotation ?
- **for point 4 -** Is there any configuration to add width and height to label, just like we have for point 3 with shape annotation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible through API options, but you can modify the created SVG elements in some chart events. For example:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const labels = this.annotations[0].labels;
        const shapes = this.annotations[0].shapes;

        shapes[0].graphic.attr({
          rx: 5,
          ry: 5
        });

        labels[1].graphic.box.attr({
          width: 100,
          height: 100
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0mxezay8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr